# How to convert google doc to clean HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to make a web app that whenever called(in my case an ajax request), will return a text output containing the doc in the html form.

I have tried [GoogleDoc2HTML](https://github.com/thejimbirch/GoogleDoc2Html/blob/master/code.js) but it has problem with formatting ordered lists.

The [Docs to Markdown add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-to-markdown/igffnbdfnodiaphfmfaiiaegmoljbghf) provided a correct version of the html.

I have also tried to download the HTML and write a converter myself. Although the lists are working, I don't know how to process the styles(bold, italic...) as those were generated as css included in the header by google doc.

Is there a way to convert a doc to html with a similar format as those produced by the Docs to Markdown add-on? Or is there a way to access the output of the add-on in google app script?

Comment: If you remove `/edit` and append `/export?format=html`, You'll get html

Comment: can I access that html file using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I went through atleast 10 questions on the same topics and I couldn't find any solutions. And finally, here I see a small comment which says "If you remove /edit and append /export?format=html, You'll get html" . Literally that's how easy it is. All credit to [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)

Answer (score -1):

Separated files can be included back into the main HTML page using template statements such as

```
<?!= include(myCSS); ?>
```

What you want to accomplish is describe in the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript